# Proof about approximations near $\sqrt{2} + 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

If $x = \sqrt2 + 1$ then $x = \frac{1}{x} + 2$.

1. Given this, how can I prove that if $y > 1$ is some approximation to $x = \sqrt2 + 1$ then $ ( \frac{1}{y} + 2 )$ is a closer approximation to $x$ than $y$ is?
2. Why one would expect, at the intuitive level, that $ ( \frac{1}{y} + 2 )$ is a closer approximation to $x$ than $y$ is?

Comment: Can you explain what your book says about "some approximation to a number $x$ " ?

Comment: I took it from here https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/ug.hndts/m104_Rudin_exs.pdf , page 3, exercise (a) and (b). I suppose by "approximation" he means "closer" as he explains it in the paragraph just above this exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are expected to notice that, since $x>1$ and $y>1$,
\begin{align}
\left|\left(\frac1y+2\right)-x\right|&=\left|\frac1y+2-\left(\frac1x+2\right)\right|\\ \ \\
&=\left|\frac1y-\frac1x\right|\\ \ \\
&=\frac{|y-x|}{xy}<|y-x|.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$f(y):= \frac{1}{y} +2$ is a [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) on $(1,\infty)$:

For $y,y' > 1$, $$|f(y)-f(y')| = \frac{|y-y'|}{yy'} \le|y-y'|.$$

Taking $y'=x$, we have
$$|f(y)-x| = |f(y)-f(x)| \le |y-x|,$$
so $f(y)$ is closer to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$|x - y| = |x-y|$ that's the error of choosing $y$.

$|(1/y +2)-x| = |(1/y+2)-(1/x +2)| =|1/y -1/x| =|(x-y)/xy|$ that's the error of choosing $1/y +2$.

As $x>1$ and $y > 1$, $|(x-y)/xy| < |x-y|$.

So the error for choosing $1/y +2$ is smaller than the error for choosing $y$.

Answer (score 1):

We are essentially exploiting the fact that the [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) of $1+\sqrt{2}$ is $$1+\sqrt{2}=[2;2,2,2,2,\ldots] \tag{1}$$
hence if $x$ is some approximation,
$$ 2+\frac{1}{x} = [2;x]\tag{2} $$
is a better approximation.